# Using RecordsAffected-method in VBA causes error when the number exceeds approximately 90.000 records?

Tags: vba, ms-access, stack-overflow, dao, insertion

I'm running an append-query in VBA (inside MS Access) that looks like the code below.
When I use the RecordsAffected-method in VBA in order to keep track of how many records that have been inserted, it causes an error when the number exceeds approximately 90.000 records and above? (some kind of stackoverflow error it says)

The funny part is, that when I don't use RecordsAffected-method, the query works just fine. And it also works fine when the number of rows affected is below 90.000.

What can be wrong? Is this a bug in VBA?
.
.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database  
sql As String  
iCount As Integer  
Set dbs = CurrentDb  

sql = "INSERT INTO " & ReceiveTable_selected & " SELECT " & NavisionTable_selected & ".* " & _
                   "FROM " & NavisionTable_selected & " " & _
                   "WHERE ((([" & NavisionTable_selected & "].[Entry No_]  ) >" &   
                    Counter_selected & "))"


dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
iCount = dbs.RecordsAffected
```

Comment: The exact error message and number would be helpful for troubleshooting this.

Comment: I just ran a test on a large insert where `RecordsAffected` reported back `2445045` records.  So it doesn't seem to be a bug in VBA or DAO.  I'm guessing there's something else going on here.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input. Maybe it could be that I append from ODBC linked tables?

Comment: I now found the exact error message: Run-time error '6': Overflow

Comment: In breakmode I can see that dbs.RecordsAffected hold the correct value, while my variable iCount is 1. Secondly dbFailOnError=128 it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Dim iCount As Integer` to `Dim iCount As Long`

From the help file:

> Integer variables are stored as 16-bit (2-byte) numbers ranging in
>   value from -32,768 to 32,767.

and:

> Long (long integer) variables are
>   stored as signed 32-bit (4-byte)
>   numbers ranging in value from
>   -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: That must be the reason. But how come this website says that Integer can hold larger values? I guess I'm using and old version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx >> Holds signed 32-bit (4-byte) integers that range in value from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.

Comment: That website is a reference for VB.Net.  Microsoft made a real mess out of things when it created Visual Basic .NET and started referring to it as simply 'Visual Basic'.  Unfortunately, it varies substantially from Visual Basic 6 (VB6) and Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)--its quasi-predecessors.  The naming scheme is a source of endless confusion for new and experienced programmers alike.